# Importing an arraylist from another class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to import ArrayList `mEpisodeList` which is inside `TvShowEpisodeLoader.java` into `TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.java`  and use an element of it namely `mEpisode` to create an Episode number scrollbar [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REq8G.jpg)  I need help to do that, I appreciate it.

I only want the `mEpisode` element from `mEpisodeList`
you can see the values of `mEpisodeList` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDJOe.jpg).

```
public class TvShowEpisodeLoader {
    
    private class TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask extends LibrarySectionAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final ArrayList<GridEpisode> mEpisodeList;

        public TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask() {
            mEpisodeList = new ArrayList<GridEpisode>();
        }
}
```

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
       // getting arraylist mEpisodeList
        //         ????????           //
        // populate tvHisPosts layout
        mlistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHisPosts);
        // Create The Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<GridEpisode> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ????????);
        // Set The Adapter
        mlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: If there is no getter for the list, the only way would be to get nasty and use reflection to access the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by initializing the mEpisodes in the fragment like this

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(this, mShowId,
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                        ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```